# How to uninstall Vertica-R-lang-version.rpm and other R language distribution from Linux 6.5?

Tags: r, vertica

I need to uninstall the all R language distributions from my server for reinstall it.

We used  `Vertica-R-lang-version.rpm` and in some nodes other R distributions.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uninstall the rpm package with the command:

```
# rpm -e vertica-R-lang
```

To install the correct version refer to the Vertica Documentation: [Installing/Upgrading the R Language Pack for Vertica](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ExtendingVertica/R/InstallingRForVertica.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already uninstalled the vertical R and other R distributions with below commands.                
 # yum remove  , yum remove R-core,yum remove R-devel,yum remove R-core-devel , rpm -e vertica-R-lang.